# Magento 1.9 :: Custom Module Admin Menu Not Displaying Items

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I have an issue on Magento 1.9.
I've just created a custom admin module, but menu items don't appear.

app/etc/modules/Pluma_Storico.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pluma_Storico>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Pluma_Storico>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Pluma/Storico/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pluma_Storico>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Pluma_Storico>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Pluma/Storico/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <sales>
            <children>
                <storico module="pluma_storico">
                    <title>Storico</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/storico/index</action>
                </storico>
            </children>
        </sales>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Were you able to find an solution on this?